# Set Global Environment variable in parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to set the value of a .GlobalEnv variable from within a parLapply call to view the progress of the task. For example:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(1)

progress <- 0
voos <- parLapply(cl, c(1,2,3),
              function(x) {
                ... some code ...
                progress <- progress + 1
                return(...)
              })

stopCluster(cl)
```

I tried using `assign('progress', get('progress', envir=.GlobalEnv) + 1, envir=.GlobalEnv)` but it doens't work.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a better option?

Comment: I do this all the time actually, but by using `write()` to push progress logs to files: `write("progress message", file = "path/to/file.log", append = T, sep = "\n")`

Comment: No - it's not possible. The parallel code is evaluated in separate R processes and those cannot update the main R process; all you can do is to return values from worker to master.  (there are workaround via files, shared memory solutions, but those are non-standard, advanced, and I leave it to someone else to comment on those).